# findOneAndUpdate - find on view and update on collection in same query?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection 'items' and a view 'items-not-deleted' created like this

```
createCollection('items-not-deleted', {
  viewOn: 'items',
  pipeline: [{ $match: { deleted: { $ne: true } } }]
})
```

I want to run an update query which finds an item in the 'items-not-deleted' view and updates it 'items' collection. Any ideas how to go about doing this in the same query?
 I have tried the following:

```
mongoClient.db('db')
.collection('items-not-deleted')
.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: new ObjectID(id) }, { $set: {name} })
```

but this is giving me the expected error `Namespace db.items-not-deleted is a view, not a collection`.

Comment: Yes, this is why I wanted to find on view and write on collection in the same query.

Comment: This can't be done the way you wan't it. either split into 2 queries or do the initial query on the `item` collection.